# Dot net core console application uses Mailkit does not send emails when deployed as azure web job

Tags: smtp, console-application, .net-core, azure-webjobs, mailkit

I am using " Mailkit " to send emails from a dot net core console application (using smtp). It works when i run the application in my local machine and I receive emails.

However, when i deployed as an azure webjob, It does not send emails. I could see the job completes successfully and no errors logged. BUT i do not receive emails

I am just wondering how it works in local machine and it does not while run in azure.

**Update:**

Based on comments below, trying to be specific. can someone confirm if you were able to use Mailkit and an organizational smtp server(no public domains) & email account to send emails from an azure webjob ? or else please suggest what should be a working setup. thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the emails aren't being caught in a spam trap?

Comment: I just tested sending mail from my WebJob and working fine on my side. Which mail server did you use? Sometimes the mail server will reject the sending mail request from a new client or different time zone(note that Azure WebJob use UTC±00:00 as the default time zone).

Comment: @jstedfast I am using my company email address. the smtp server also belongs to my organization. Do you think the cause could be Mailkit? should i use a different smtp library that would work in an azure hosted env?

Comment: @Amor pls refer to my earlier comment. I am using smtp & email provided by my organization. Are you using Mailkit by the way? or do you use a different provider? I could see you mentioned yours is an azure webjob..

Comment: I guarantee that the problem is not with MailKit. Most likely  the server is trapping the message for some reason - like Amor said, you might need to authenticate on your web server via a web browser to get the smtp server to recognize your web server.

Comment: @jstedfast I see, you might be correct, at present i am using the default port 25 which does not require authentication. i will try out with authentication and get back.

Comment: Meanwhile, @Amor could you please post your code that works.? I'm interested in knowing which smtp provider you are using. that works with your webjob. thanks!

Comment: I was using Google mail server to send mail. I will post my sample code when I back to office.

Comment: If you are using GMail, you *definitely* need to authenticate in a browser before you can authenticate in MailKit because GMail requires web login from an IP before you can login via SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

> can someone confirm if you were able to use Mailkit and an organizational smtp server(no public domains) & email account to send emails from an azure webjob ? or else please suggest what should be a working setup. thanks!

No public domain means that we can't access the smtp server through the internet. As a workaround, you could save the mail information to a Azure Queue Storage from the WebJob and writing a new application and publish it to your internal network. In your new application, you could get the information from Azure queue storage and send the mail from your internal network.